# Geoserver overload

Tags: geoserver

we've been using Geoserver v2.2.5 for quite a while and we've started experiencing difficulties recently. Currently we have about 7 000 layers published in Geoserver served via WMS.

What happens is we get "exceeded memory buffer" error when accessing the map. It seems to happen randomly, unrelated to any of the published layers. What bothers me is that the problem occurs with very small number of users using the map (actually we are able to overload Geoserver with 4 concurrent PCs accessing its layers). The request is sent to Geoserver, but it is never finished and hangs somewhere between the server and Geoserver. It all ends up with Geoserver getting stuck and unresponsive (needs to be shutdown manually).

We've tried rising timeout for requests (did not help), switching from OpenJDK to Oracle Java (did not help).

I've run out of ideas. Has any of you ever experienced anything like this? I'm looking for solution as well as for your user experience: how many layers is published on your Geoserver, how many people access them?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your GeoServer hosted on a regular PC which serves as server, or on a proper server ? This might (even though not much) have a certain influence on the limit before which the server crashes.

Comment: It is hosted on a proper server (VPS to be precise).

Answer (score 2):

Geoserver can be a real memory hog, and sometimes needs to be tuned to handle things.

Ensuring you've optimized your servlet is the first step.  You can find information on how to do that [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html).

Most key of those would be running with these options:

> -Xmx256M -Xms48m - Allocates extra memory to your server.

For hard mode tuning, you could mess with the [garbage collection](http://www.petefreitag.com/articles/gctuning/).  Also ensure you've properly configured tile caching, especially if you are serving coverages.

Another thing you could look into would be upgrading to 2.3.x and take advantage of the [Catalog Scalability Enhancements](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GSIP+69+-+Catalog+scalability+enhancements).  Copied from linked:

> Improved vertical scalability of Catalog resources (i.e. being able to efficiently manage hundreds of thousands of layers, styles, etc).

At the very least, that would help you manage all your layers.